# Why does it take so long to load?

Tags: php, html

Basically I'm trying to display images downloaded from FTP with their previews to a dropdown list. Well, I did it but I've recently noticed that large images load in their full size and the website got really clumsy with animations and stuff (and also loading it for the first time).
Then I wrote the code below, inspired by various sources from the Internet. I managed it to work but now the website loads even slower. What's wrong? Do I give up with this idea and just upload previews to my FTP everytime when uploading an image or is there a way to speed it up?

```php
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
  $length = strlen($needle);
  if ($length == 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}

function resize_image($file, $w) {
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
  $newwidth = $w;
  $newheight = ($w * $height) / $width;
  if (endsWith($file, '.png')) {
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
  } else if (endsWith($file, '.jpeg') || endsWith($file, '.jpg')) {
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
  } else if (endsWith($file, '.webp')) {
    $src = imagecreatefromwebp($file);
  } else if (endsWith($file, '.gif')) {
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
  }
  $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
  imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

  return $dst;
}

$images = scandir(__DIR__.
  '/'.
  'uploads/'.$_SESSION['id']);
$images = array_values(array_diff($images, array('.', '..', 'comments')));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
  $img = $images[$i];
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $imga = resize_image(__DIR__.
    '/'.
    'uploads/'.$_SESSION['id'].
    '/'.$img, 100);
  ob_start();
  imagejpeg($imga, NULL, 100);
  imagedestroy($imga);
  $imgb = ob_get_clean();
  $imgb = base64_encode($imgb);
echo << EOL;
  <option value="$img" data-icon="data:image/jpeg;base64,$imgb">$img</option>
EOL;
}
```

Outputs to div:

```html
<div class="your-files input-field col s12 m6" id="your-avatars">
    <select class="icons">
        <option selected disabled value="default">Wybierz obrazek...</option>
        <!-- here comes the PHP output -->
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You should cache thumbnails

Comment: Effectively your image creation process makes it slower to work you can first download all the images and then display them from local directory